# Weird behaviour with Select.Async and loadOptions

Tags: react-select

I have a question about react-select component.

I have following code (coffeescript) and very weird behaviour (on the gif below). The question is -- waht I'm doing wrong? Why options not shown immediately after the `getOptions` func done? Why they shown only after the click outside? That's super confusing.. I need your help guys!

```
getOptions = (value) =>
  return Promise.resolve({options: []}) unless value
  api.geocoder(value).then (data) =>
    countries = [
      {value: 'A', label: 'A'}
      {value: 'B', label: 'B'}
    ]
    console.info(countries)
    {options: countries}

<Select.Async
  className="ads-filter__select"
  value={@props.country_code}
  onChange={(option) => @props.onChange('country_code', option)}
  clearable={false}
  placeholder={I18n.t('ads.country')}
  loadOptions={getOptions}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property to Select.Async: filterOption={() => (true)}
To be more specific write:

```
<Select.Async
  className="ads-filter__select"
  value={@props.country_code}
  filterOption={() => (true)}
  onChange={(option) => @props.onChange('country_code', option)}
  clearable={false}
  placeholder={I18n.t('ads.country')}
  loadOptions={getOptions}
/>
```

Hope this will solve your issue